# BPI in Cohen Model

Tags: logic, set-theory, boolean-algebra, foundations, forcing

I'm reading Miroslav Repicky's paper "A proof of the independence of the Axiom of Choice from the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem" and I'm confused by the claim that an ideal $I$ on a Boolean algebra $B$ being prime in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ implies that it must be a maximal ideal of $B$ in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$. For context, below is a screenshot of the relevant section of the argument:

[image]

My concern is that while $I$ selects between $x$ and $\neg x$ for every $x\in B\cap OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$, it is possible that there is some ideal $I'\subseteq B\setminus OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ so that $I$ and $I'$ generate a larger proper ideal $J$ of $B$, with $I,I',J\in OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$. In other words, if $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ is not transitive, $I$ may be prime here without being maximal.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: It seems like the argument runs properly if we take $k$ to be the least natural number so that for some $h'\in^{k+1}A$, $I$ is not maximal in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h']$ and make the appropriate minor adjustments from this point onwards.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is not trying to show $I$ is prime in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$, it is trying to show that $I$ is prime in $M$.  I think this is what you're confused about.

I'll try to repeat relevant parts of their argument.  As they described, you can construct $I$.  $I\subseteq B$, so every element of $I$ is in $M$, and $I$ has the same support as $B$, so $I\in M$.  We want to show that $M\models I\text{ is prime}$; that is, for every $x\in M$, either $x\in I$ or $\lnot x\in I$.  It will follow that $M\models I\text{ is maximal}$.

Suppose for contradiction that $I$ is not prime in $M$.  Then there must be some $x\in M$ so that neither $x$ nor $\lnot x$ is in $I$.  Let us choose such an $x$ with minimal support.

[the rest of their argument will reach a contradiction from assuming $x$ has minimal support; it's not in the screenshot so I assume you understood it]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that the goal of the argument is to show that $I$ is prime in $M$. My confusion is that it seems that the maximality of $I$ in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ is something that is crucially used later on when it is stated that "The ideal of $B$ generated by $I\cup\{d(a):a\in U\cap A\}$ is in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ and it coincides with $B$ by maximality of $I$. Therefore for some finite set $F'_1\subseteq U\cap A$ we have $\bigwedge_{a\in F'_1}-d(a)\in I$."

Comment: The "maximality of $I$" that they use here seems to be in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$, since $h$ is used to define $U$ (and thus the generated ideal they mention). But maximality in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ was shown by primeness in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$, where primeness here is true since $x$ was chosen with the minimal support that you mention and $|f\frown h|$ is smaller than this support. I'm still confused as to why maximality in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ follows from primeness, since it seems like maximality here is critically used to get the conjunction quoted above.

Comment: $h$ has a shorter length than $h'$.  $x$ was taken to be supported by $h'$, and $x$ was taken to have minimal sized support.
This means $I$ is prime in $OD^{V[G]} [A,f\frown h]$, because any any $y\in OD^{V[G]} [A,f\frown h]$ has smaller support than $x$, so either $y\in I$ or $\lnot y\in I$.

Comment: Oh sorry seems you were typing basically what I said at the same time as me.

Comment: No problem, I noticed we must have been typing at the same time :) Maybe it's the case that the correct claim is "The ideal of $B$ generated by $I\cup\{d(a):a\in U\cap A\}$ is in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f]$," in which case $I$ is maximal here by construction... but then I'm not sure why they even mention earlier that $I$ is maximal in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$, since it seems unnecessary if this is the correct statement.

Comment: Okay, thinking about it some more, $B\cap OD^{V[G]}[A,f]$ is not really something you want to be thinking about; it is missing most elements of $B$.  The definition they give for $I$ is something like "find a definition in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f]$ and then interpret that definition in $HOD^{V[G]}[A,f]$".  They may be using the word "maximal" to distinguish this sort of construction from "prime", a condition on elements that can be checked in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f]$

Comment: The way I've understood the result is that $B\cap OD^{V[G]}[A,f]$ and $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ both miss most elements of $B$, as you mention, but can still have $S\in OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ with $S\subseteq B$ and $S$ not a subset of $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$. An ideal can be prime in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ without being maximal if there are more sets $S\in OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ of this form that can union with the ideal to grow it, despite the ideal having already decided on all singletons in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$. Thus prime doesn't imply maximal in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$.

Comment: From what I can tell, the conclusion that $I$ is maximal in $OD^{V[G]}[A,f\frown h]$ from the fact that it is prime, and the resulting $\bigwedge_{a\in F'_1}-d(a)\in I$, is how the author replaces the use of the Halpern-Lauchli theorem in the general case of this argument presented by Halpern and Levy.

Comment: If it helps, the proof I know of this fact (actually a slightly more general fact) is in this paper.  I'm not sure if the extra generality here will make the argument more or less clear
https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=471d2e68d176fabacf8e3d02f40e624ec1c72dee